# How to install Tortoise TTS + RVC (no matter which one)?

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, tortoisesvn, text-to-speech

I tried to install many different TTS and RVC tools including tortoise, coqui, etc
But I always got an error message while installing the program.
Please explain how to install Tortoise on my PC.

I would like to create "audio books" for myself about sciences, but it's recent knowledge.
My PC has Intel and AMD for graphics cards, then please don't advice me to install Nvidia software.

I tried to install Tortoise and many other tools on my PC but it didn't work. I would like to create "audio books" for myself about sciences.